# Jprofiler config

Tags: java, jprofiler

I'm trying to evaluate jProfiler with a standalone java 1.5 console app.
The docs say to add -agentpath:[path to jprofilerti library].

What is the jprofilerti library?

Do I add this parameter to my console app when I start it up?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to execute

Session->Integration Wizards->New Remote Integration

in the JProfiler GUI. The wizard will tell you the exact VM parameter that has to be added to the Java invocation.

> What is the jprofilerti library?

It's the native library named "jprofilerti" that is located in the `bin/[platform]` directory of your JProfiler installation.